# How to use sys.stdin.read() on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, input, sys

I found this python3 code in a tutorial case. I don't understand how the sys.stdin.read() works on a mac. The input command starts but I cannot close it. If I press ctrl + D, apparently nothing happens. If I press cmd + D, I get exit code 0.

```
import sys

def get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    for _ in range(n - 1):
        previous, current = current, previous + current

    return current % 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n = int(input)
    print(get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you understand how `sys.stdin.read()` itself works.

On a Mac, the `CMD` key is the equivalent of the `Ctrl` key on a Windows PC. That is why Mac expects the user to press `CMD` + `D` to finish their entry.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found an issue in my interpreter setup, that cause my error. Thanks for the reply